# how to open another activity in android using a button

Tags: java, android, android-activity

so the code below is not doing the proper function it is called to do
it is supposed to open up a new activity upon a click of a button, but instead
nothing happens buttons display and no errors
and this stupid website is requiring me to explain a little more so im just going type random nonsense until it lets me post my question

```
package com.Tripp.thebasics;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Menu extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //setting up the button references
        Button jokeD = (Button) findViewById(R.id.jokeoftheday);
        Button jokeC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.jokecatagories);

        jokeD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(Menu.this, JokeOfTheDay.class));

            }
        });

        jokeC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent s = new Intent("com.Tripp.thebasics.JOKECATAGORIES");
                startActivity(s);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you changed the manifest file according to the new activities?

Comment: If you are new to Android, then go through this website, http://www.skholingua.com/android-basic/android-app-components/activity-intents, it might helps you alot to learn

Comment: yes the manifest file was changed

Answer (score 0):

Help with creating an `intent` such that you can call an activity when a button is clicked. Also need help declaring an activity in a manifest file:

```
 myBtn.setOnClickListener() {
        public void onClick() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

Comment: you don't even have the parameters needed in the setOnClickListener method

Answer (score 0):

1. create seperate xml and java files for new activity.
2. Create on click listener like below for the button.
   `Button.setOnClickListener() {
       public void onClick() {
           Intent myintent = new Intent(this, newactivity.class);
           startActivity(myintent);
       }
   }`

3.add new activity on android manifest.xml file.

`<application>`

```
`<activity android:name=".classname" ></activity>`
```

`</application`

If you want more clarifications ,inform me

Comment: yes i am getting an error when using "this" its saying the constructor intent is undefined or something. also this is not the main activity class this is a seperate class named "menu"

Answer (score 0):

```
jokeD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            startActivity(new Intent(this,    JokeOfTheDay.class));

            }
         });
```

And make sure you have your new class in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
            android:name=".youractivitypackagename.JokeOfTheDay"
            android:label="JokeOfTheDay" >
</activity>
```

EDIT: 
Take a look here for a better explanation of how to declare an activity in the Manifest, as it depends on how you declare the package: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html.

If your package for your class is, for example, com.example.project.Test, then you should have the following, within the  tags:

```
<activity
                android:name="com.example.project.Test.JokeOfTheDay"
                android:label="JokeOfTheDay" >
 </activity>
```

Comment: your class namespace? where would i get that?

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".JokeCatagories"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.JOKECATAGORIES" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: Just edited my answer; yourclassnamespace if, in fact, yourclasspackagename, sorry for the misundestanding, C# style :).

Comment: sorry but i got it answered myself turns out i wasnt using the main class and thats what it was if you know anything about the canvas class and a button let me know!